# Altering date in list of dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, dictionary, text

**Background**

I have a list of dictionary values

```
list_of_dic = [{'id': 'T1','type': 'LOCATION-OTHER','start': 142,'end': 148,'text': 'California'},
 {'id': 'T2', 'type': 'PHONE', 'start': 342, 'end': 352, 'text': '123456789'},
 {'id': 'T3', 'type': 'DATE', 'start': 679, 'end': 687, 'text': '1/1/2000'},
 {'id': 'T10','type': 'DOCTOR','start': 692,'end': 701,'text': 'Joe'},
 {'id': 'T11', 'type': 'DATE', 'start': 702, 'end': 710, 'text': '5/1/2000'}]
```

**Goal**

1) Locate all `'type': 'DATE'` in `list_of_dict`

2) Add `2` days to the corresponding `'text: 'value'`

**Example**

`{'id': 'T3', 'type': 'DATE', 'start': 679, 'end': 687, 'text': '1/1/2000'}`

will become

`{'id': 'T3', 'type': 'DATE', 'start': 679, 'end': 687, 'text': '1/3/2000'}`

**Desired Output**

```
 desired_list_of_dic = [{'id': 'T1','type': 'LOCATION-OTHER','start': 142,'end': 148,'text': 'California'},
     {'id': 'T2', 'type': 'PHONE', 'start': 342, 'end': 352, 'text': '123456789'},
     {'id': 'T3', 'type': 'DATE', 'start': 679, 'end': 687, 'text': '1/3/2000'},
     {'id': 'T10','type': 'DOCTOR','start': 692,'end': 701,'text': 'Joe'},
     {'id': 'T11', 'type': 'DATE', 'start': 702, 'end': 710, 'text': '5/3/2000'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `datetime` module

**Ex:**

```
import datetime

list_of_dic = [{'id': 'T1','type': 'LOCATION-OTHER','start': 142,'end': 148,'text': 'California'},
 {'id': 'T2', 'type': 'PHONE', 'start': 342, 'end': 352, 'text': '123456789'},
 {'id': 'T3', 'type': 'DATE', 'start': 679, 'end': 687, 'text': '1/1/2000'},
 {'id': 'T10','type': 'DOCTOR','start': 692,'end': 701,'text': 'Joe'},
 {'id': 'T11', 'type': 'DATE', 'start': 702, 'end': 710, 'text': '5/1/2000'}]

for i in list_of_dic:           #Iterate list
    if i["type"] == 'DATE':     #Check 'type'
        i["text"] = (datetime.datetime.strptime(i["text"], "%m/%d/%Y") + datetime.timedelta(days=2)).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")   #Increment days. 

print(list_of_dic)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'end': 148,
  'id': 'T1',
  'start': 142,
  'text': 'California',
  'type': 'LOCATION-OTHER'},
 {'end': 352, 'id': 'T2', 'start': 342, 'text': '123456789', 'type': 'PHONE'},
 {'end': 687, 'id': 'T3', 'start': 679, 'text': '01/03/2000', 'type': 'DATE'},
 {'end': 701, 'id': 'T10', 'start': 692, 'text': 'Joe', 'type': 'DOCTOR'},
 {'end': 710, 'id': 'T11', 'start': 702, 'text': '05/03/2000', 'type': 'DATE'}]
```

- `datetime.timedelta(days=N)` --> to increment days
- `datetime.datetime.strptime` --> to convert string to datetime object
- `strftime` --> to convert datetime object to string

Comment: How would the code change if we wanted to create a new list from the output? I created a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57137423/creating-a-new-list-from-list-of-dictionaries Maybe you have insight?