# Creating a new list from list of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, dictionary, text

**Background**

The following code works for adding 2 days to a date (e.g. `1/1/2000` becomes `1/3/2000` and is taken from [Altering date in list of dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57117475/altering-date-in-list-of-dictionary/57117530#57117530)

```
import datetime

list_of_dic = [{'id': 'T1','type': 'LOCATION-OTHER','start': 142,'end': 148,'text': 'California'},
 {'id': 'T2', 'type': 'PHONE', 'start': 342, 'end': 352, 'text': '123456789'},
 {'id': 'T3', 'type': 'DATE', 'start': 679, 'end': 687, 'text': '1/1/2000'},
 {'id': 'T10','type': 'DOCTOR','start': 692,'end': 701,'text': 'Joe'},
 {'id': 'T11', 'type': 'DATE', 'start': 702, 'end': 710, 'text': '5/1/2000'}]

for i in list_of_dic:           #Iterate list
    if i["type"] == 'DATE':     #Check 'type'
        i["text"] = (datetime.datetime.strptime(i["text"], "%m/%d/%Y") + datetime.timedelta(days=2)).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")   #Increment days. 

print(list_of_dic)
```

**Output**

```
[{'id': 'T1', 'type': 'LOCATION-OTHER', 'start': 142, 'end': 148, 'text': 'California'}, 
   {'id': 'T2', 'type': 'PHONE', 'start': 342, 'end': 352, 'text': '123456789'}, 
   {'id': 'T3', 'type': 'DATE', 'start': 679, 'end': 687, 'text': '01/03/2000'}, 
  {'id': 'T10', 'type': 'DOCTOR', 'start': 692, 'end': 701, 'text': 'Joe'}, 
 {'id': 'T11', 'type': 'DATE', 'start': 702, 'end': 710, 'text': '05/03/2000'}]
```

**Question**

How would the code change if one wanted to save the output from `print(list_of_dic)` in a new list called `new_list_of_dic`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `copy`?

```
new_list_of_dic = list_of_dic.copy()
```

Or if you want the string?

```
new_list_of_dic = str(list_of_dic)
```